# Spring Flux<Part> doOnNext not executed

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, multipart, flux

I'm using Reactive Spring for file upload and I can't quite understand how this works.

```java
// Code 1
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public Mono<Void> upload(@RequestPart("key") Flux<Part> partFlux) {
    return partFlux
            .log(null, Level.INFO)
            .doOnNext(part -> {
                logger.info("[Return] " + part.name(), part.headers());
            })
            .then();
}
```

This receives a multipart request and logs its parts successfully.

However, the next version doesn't work:

```java
// Code 2
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public void upload(@RequestPart("key") Flux<Part> partFlux) {
    partFlux
            .log(null, Level.INFO)
            .doOnNext(part -> {
                logger.info("[Subscribe] " + part.name(), part.headers());
            })
            .subscribe();
}
```

The difference is this does not returns but subscribes to the input `Flux`, which I expect to work as same as Code 1. However in the execution log, even though `subscribe` itself was successfully called, logging was not performed.

So I assumed that somehow Spring ignores/skips the inner subscription, but this was also not true.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public void upload(@RequestPart("key") Flux<Part> partFlux) {
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .log(null, Level.INFO)
            .doOnNext(v -> {
                logger.info("[Inner] " + v.toString());
            })
            .subscribe();
}
```

This successfully runs the inner subscription and creates log.

I'm confused why Code 1 and 2 works differently, mainly how `doOnNext` in Code 2 gets ignored.

**Appendix**

- Execution logs of Code 1

```
2021-10-18 14:28:41.932 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [c5c6915b-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56565] HTTP POST "/upload", headers={masked}
2021-10-18 14:28:41.944 DEBUG 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [c5c6915b-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56565] Mapped to com.healthhub.rxstudy.rest.FluxUploadController#upload(Flux)
2021-10-18 14:28:41.962  INFO 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlattenIterable.1       : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxFlattenIterable.FlattenIterableSubscriber)
2021-10-18 14:28:41.964  INFO 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlattenIterable.1       : | request(unbounded)
2021-10-18 14:28:41.981 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : First boundary found @39 in PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 228, cap: 228/228, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.982 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Changed state: PREAMBLE -> HEADERS
2021-10-18 14:28:41.982 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : End of headers found @47 in PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 188, cap: 188/188, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.983 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Emitting headers: [Content-Disposition:"form-data; name="key""]
2021-10-18 14:28:41.986 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.http.codec.multipart.PartGenerator   : Changed state: INITIAL -> FORM-FIELD
2021-10-18 14:28:41.986 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Changed state: HEADERS -> BODY
2021-10-18 14:28:41.987 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Boundary found @43 in PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 140, cap: 140/140, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.987 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Emitting body: PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 2, cap: 2/2, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.987 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Changed state: BODY -> HEADERS
2021-10-18 14:28:41.988 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : End of headers found @47 in PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 96, cap: 96/96, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.988 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Emitting headers: [Content-Disposition:"form-data; name="key""]
2021-10-18 14:28:41.989 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.http.codec.multipart.PartGenerator   : Emitting: DefaultFormFieldPart{key}
2021-10-18 14:28:41.990 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.http.codec.multipart.PartGenerator   : Changed state: FORM-FIELD -> FORM-FIELD
2021-10-18 14:28:41.990 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Changed state: HEADERS -> BODY
2021-10-18 14:28:41.990 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Boundary found @43 in PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 48, cap: 48/48, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.990 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Emitting body: PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 2, cap: 2/2, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.990 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Changed state: BODY -> HEADERS
2021-10-18 14:28:41.990 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Last boundary found in PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 4, cap: 4/4, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 1471, widx: 1471, cap: 2048))
2021-10-18 14:28:41.991 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.codec.multipart.MultipartParser    : Changed state: HEADERS -> DISPOSED
2021-10-18 14:28:41.991 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.http.codec.multipart.PartGenerator   : Emitting: DefaultFormFieldPart{key}
2021-10-18 14:28:41.991 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.c.m.MultipartHttpMessageReader     : [c5c6915b-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56565] Parsed parts [key] (content masked)
2021-10-18 14:28:41.992  INFO 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlattenIterable.1       : | onNext(DefaultFormFieldPart{key})
2021-10-18 14:28:41.992  INFO 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.h.rxstudy.rest.FluxUploadController    : [Return] key
2021-10-18 14:28:41.992  INFO 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlattenIterable.1       : | onNext(DefaultFormFieldPart{key})
2021-10-18 14:28:41.992  INFO 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.h.rxstudy.rest.FluxUploadController    : [Return] key
2021-10-18 14:28:41.992  INFO 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlattenIterable.1       : | onComplete()
2021-10-18 14:28:41.993 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [c5c6915b-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56565] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2021-10-18 14:28:41.994 TRACE 39084 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [c5c6915b-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56565] Handling completed
```

- Execution logs of Code 2

```
2021-10-18 14:24:59.157 TRACE 37416 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [ff1c78e0-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61525] HTTP POST "/upload", headers={masked}
2021-10-18 14:24:59.173 DEBUG 37416 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [ff1c78e0-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61525] Mapped to com.healthhub.rxstudy.rest.FluxUploadController#upload(Flux)
2021-10-18 14:24:59.190  INFO 37416 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlattenIterable.1       : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxFlattenIterable.FlattenIterableSubscriber)
2021-10-18 14:24:59.191  INFO 37416 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlattenIterable.1       : | request(unbounded)
2021-10-18 14:24:59.207 TRACE 37416 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [ff1c78e0-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61525] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2021-10-18 14:24:59.209 TRACE 37416 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [ff1c78e0-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61525] Handling completed
```

Comment: Looks like the Flux<Part> parameter passed to your controller initially is not bound with real partition parser. Probably they do it only after call to your controller method. If so, they after call to your method, connect partition parser to the Flux, and then subscribe the Mono<Void> you chained to Flux parameter in Code 1.
In Code 2 you try to subscribe to Flux before it is actually bound to partition parser.
This is just a hypothesis, but it can explain the observed phenomenon.